# GLIBCXX not found in local built libstdc++.so.6 GCC10.2.0 on REHL7.4 and CentOS8

Tags: gcc, g++, libstdc++

I have two servers one of which is running RHEL 7.4 and the other one is CentOS 8
the RHEL comes with gcc 4.8.5 and libc.so.6 at 2.17
the CentOS comes with gcc 8.3.1 and libc 2.28

I built a GCC 10.2 on both server and install to customized path something like /dist/gcc/10.2.0
to built the GCC 10.2, I also built gmp 6.2.0, mpc 1.1.0 and mpfr 4.0.2, those three libs are also install under my customized path like /dist/gmp/6.2.0..

things has been smooth on both servers for a long time, I built all kinds of customized library on both REHL and CentOS with my brand new GCC10.2.
However last week I started to build a simple C++ application which links a 3rd party lib( shared object) built with old gcc(4.7 4.8 likely), I know there could be ABI issues so I took that seriously and tried building on both servers.
The result is surprising, without D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0, CentOS environment builds smoothly
but the REHL one complains with something like /......./linux64-demo/../../libs/LINUX64/libsomething.so: undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(double)@GLIBCXX_3.4' which I believe has something to do with ABI, or linking wrong lib, I tried both with and without flag D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI, the result is same.

So I did
strings /dist/gcc/10.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
'''

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

'''

and I did the same on the REHL server
'''

```
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.6
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.16
GLIBC_2.17
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
__strtof_l@@GLIBC_2.2.5
symlink@@GLIBC_2.2.5
chdir@@GLIBC_2.2.5
fileno@@GLIBC_2.2.5
pthread_cond_destroy@@GLIBC_2.3.2
__strcoll_l@@GLIBC_2.2.5
__nl_langinfo_l@@GLIBC_2.2.5
dgettext@@GLIBC_2.2.5
fseeko64@@GLIBC_2.2.5
wmemcpy@@GLIBC_2.2.5
memset@@GLIBC_2.2.5
mbrtowc@@GLIBC_2.2.5
wcslen@@GLIBC_2.2.5
close@@GLIBC_2.2.5
__duplocale@@GLIBC_2.2.5
ioctl@@GLIBC_2.2.5
abort@@GLIBC_2.2.5
......
```

'''

it looks like the libstdc++.so.6 I built on REHL does not contain GLIBCXX3.4
even thou both hosts were building the exact same GCC10.2.0 with same dependencies.

Does it have anything to do with the glibc that comes with the OS? Do I need to build a newer glibc on REHL and then rebuild GCC linking with the new glibc to solve this?

Comment: Do you have the source of the 3rdparty library? I suggest rebuilding the 3rdparty library with gcc10

Comment: Rebuild glibc and install it on Linux is complex work and very dangerous, so it's not a good choice.

Comment: Or you may try dockers on the two machines, then you have two identical Linux distro.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin I dont have the source code of that 3rd party lib. I have built the glibc 2.28 on REHL and install into a customized location, still trying to figure out link the customized built glibc with the gcc 10.2. I will try dokcer later if I cant get gcc built with new glibc

Comment: With docker you just choose the same operating system, then you don't need to build glibc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a whole weekend trail and error, I found that the reason behind all these is
because of the aging binutils that comes with the OS

I was inspired by this post
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596280/no-version-symbols-in-freshly-compiled-libstdc

simply build a newer version binutils and use that to build the gcc 10.2 solves all these problems.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on CentOS Stream 8. (originally not from me)

- wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
- sh Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
- cp anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26 /usr/lib64
- rm /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
- ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.26 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6

To Check:

- strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).